# BindingExpression collection in BindingGroup is always empty

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to implement save functionality for the page. For this, I have two way binding on my controls with UpdateSourceTrigger value set as "Explicit". I'm using the explicit option so that my bound view model property doesn't change immediately upon making change and it only change when I press "Save" button. If I press, "Cancel" button, I will leave my page without updating the bindings so that my original values don't change.

I want to make use of BindingGroup and want to update bindings on all my controls in one go. I have code implement as shown below but here the problem is, I don't get any value in BindingExpression collection of BindingGroup and it always remains empty. I understand, I should get all the bindings for which matching binding group name is set should be part of BindingGroup.BindingExpressions collection. Because of this even if I call "BindingGroup.UpdateSources()", I don't get new values updated to my view model.

Can you pls go through following code n suggest what is wrong (i.e. either my understanding about BindingGroup or my implementation)

**XAML code**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup x:Name="Group"/>
        </StackPanel.BindingGroup>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding P1, Mode=TwoWay, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding P2, Mode=TwoWay, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding P3, Mode=TwoWay, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

        <Button Content="Update Values" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            this.DataContext = new VM();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Group.UpdateSources();
        }
    }

    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _p1, _p2, _p3;

        public string P1
        {
            get
            {
                return _p1;
            }
            set
            {
                _p1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("P1");
            }
        }

        public string P2
        {
            get
            {
                return _p2;
            }
            set
            {
                _p2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("P2");
            }
        }

        public string P3
        {
            get
            {
                return _p3;
            }
            set
            {
                _p3 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("P3");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Binding should be ok, I can update properties of `VM`.

Try it.

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding P1, Mode=OneWayToSource, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
<TextBox Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding P2, Mode=OneWayToSource, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
<TextBox Name="TextBox3" Text="{Binding P3, Mode=OneWayToSource, BindingGroupName=Group, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

 public partial class Window2 : Window
{

    public Window2()
    {
        this.DataContext = new VM();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression be = TextBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Now, the TextBox's value will refresh after clicking Button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but looks like I couldn't explain my question properly.

User will edit the values inside text box. When I call Group.UpdateSources(), I expect changed values from textbox to get transferred to my viewmodel object properties. But it is not happening. I guess it is because when I check "Group.BindingExpression" collection it has noting inside it. So no binding expressions and no update to viewmodel properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware about updating the values by extracting binding expression for each control and call updatesource on it. But I was wondering is there anyway to call the updatesource method on all the bindingexpression in one go? I was under impression that BindingGroup can help me to achieve this but it seems it doesn't work that way. I'm really not able to understand now what is the reason of implementing BindingGroup?

Comment: @user2185592, BindingGroupName works for Validation, it dosen't work for updating value....... UpdateSource is useful to update source.